# Truly selecting in HTML tags in Vim

Tags: html, vim

In an HTML doc say I have this:

```
<p>
  fdhjfkdj hfkjdfhkjdfhkjdh dfhdkf kjdh kjdhkjdhk 
  fhkdj hdjfhjkdh kjdh kjdf jkdhf d
  jfdfhkdjfhkjdf 
  fjdj fhkd fdhfkjd hfkjdfhkjdf kdhfd 
  fdhjkfjk dhjdfhkjdf kjdfhdk fhdk 
</p>
```

If I do the normal `vit` command in vim it'll select the text inside if I yank it, *but* if I try to do anything such as tab over or run `gq`it affects the entire `<p>`. For example, doing `vit` then `gq` ends up looking something like

```
    <p> fdhjfkdj hfkjdfhkjdfhkjdh dfhdkf kjdh kjdhkjdhk  lkd sldj lks jlkdf
jlsdkf jlsdf jdl dlsjl fhkdj hdjfhjkdh kjdh kjdf jkdhf d jfdfhkdjfhkjdf fjdj
fhkd fdhfkjd hfkjdfhkjdf kdhfd fdhjkfjk dhjdfhkjdf kjdfhdk fhdk </p>
```

Indenting it wont indent the text, but the whole tag. How do I truly select on the the text inside so I can run commands on it like the ones above?

Answer (score 3):

That's because the inner HTML of the paragraph starts immediately after the starting `<p>` tag, so it includes the newline character immediately after it (which you'll also see after `vit`). As you've recognized, reformatting and indenting are line-based, so that single character counts.

To make the text object work like you want, you need to move to the start of the selection (`o`), then reduce it to the next line (easiest with `j`; for indenting and formatting, the exact start column isn't important, anyway). So the sequence for reformatting would be:

```
vitojgq
```

If you want something quicker, you need to write your own text object. Have a look at my [CountJump plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3130), or the [textobj-user plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2100); they can help with defining one.

Comment: the actual sequence is a bit longer: `vitkojgq` but I don't think that would have "clicked" in my mind until you explained it. Thanks! Maybe i can turn this into a shortcut of some type

Comment: Right, unless the end tag starts on column 1, as in your example!